# All citations showing up as "?"; Display I cannot explain in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, xetex, citing, mla-style

I have written a paper in MLA format, using XeLaTeX, and am now trying to make my citations work.

After first compiling with XeLaTeX, then with BibTeX, then twice more with XeLaTeX, I end up with `(?)` as all of my citations. Additionally, all of the last names and year show up in brackets on the finished bibliography:

> [BlaineBlaine2009] Blaine, David. ``How I held my breath for 17 minutes.'' October 2009.

This is the corresponding warning from the second execution of XeLaTeX:

```
[2] [3] (./diving.bbl
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \protect \citeauthoryear 
                                {Blaine}{Blaine}{2009}
l.8 ...teauthoryear{Blaine}{Blaine}{2009}]{blaine}
```

This is the corresponding portion of the `.bbl` file:

```
\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Blaine}{Blaine}{2009}]{blaine}
Blaine, David.
\newblock ``How I held my breath for 17 minutes.''
\newblock October 2009.
```

Minimum Working Example, as requested:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{harvard}

\citationstyle{mla}

\begin{document}

This is a citation\cite{blaine}.

\bibliographystyle{mla}
\bibliography{bibliography-file}

\end{document}
```

Where `bibliography-file.bib` contains:

```
@conference{blaine,
    howpublished = {TED Talks},
    month = {October},
    author = {David Blaine},
    title = {How I held my breath for 17 minutes},
    year = {2009},
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [an example of mine](https://github.com/vermiculus/smcm-tex/blob/b4a8f7c801b0e35c3ff6d66eeefbd01c613e1d6f/psyc/psypaper.cls#L18), from line 13--27 (adjust for mla).  Does that help?  (Also: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.)

Comment: Does the `harvard` package recognize an `mla` citation style?  I know there is one for `biblatex`.

Comment: Have you tried loading the `natbib` package? Doing so will probably get rid of the bracketed material at the start of each bibliographic entry.

Comment: @Mico: I used natbib, and it eliminated the bracketed material, but now the `?`s are no longer in parentheses.   
@jon: It appears to, because the citations are in perfect MLA, except for the bracketed text.

Comment: I removed `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\setmainfont{...}`, then added `\usepackage{times}` and changed it to `LaTeX` instead of `XeLaTeX`. Also, I found that I had made a mistake when using `natbib`, per @Micro's suggestion. I also needed to change the citations to `\citep{...}`.

Comment: Now if I change anything, such as to remove the boxes for the links, it breaks everything. But as long as I leave the green boxes around the links, it works perfectly.

Comment: For some reason, `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}` has to be the first line after the documentclass. If I do that, I achieve the desired results. All of my problems have been resolved. Thank you.

Comment: @hxtk That generally isn't a viable solution; if there are any other packages that would take advantage of `hyperref`, those packages won't function properly.  `hyperref` generally has to be one of the last packages loaded.

Comment: @SeanAllred: While this is true (and I did not know that, so thank you for telling me), this is MLA, so there are no other uses for `hyperref`.